# what's the best way to call a normal method in async way?

Tags: c#, .net

Just have a normal method like

void DosomethingLong()

What's the best way to call it in an async way?

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework?

Comment: Best way according to which criterias?

Comment: @DHN: "Criteria" is the plural of "criterion". :)
(I couldn't resist.)

Comment: Well there is no day without learning something new, thx. (I'm not a native speaker.) Sorry for your inconvenience. ;o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way is to create a delegate of the method:

```
Action myMethod = DosomethingLong;
```

then execute it asynchronously using the [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx)):

```
IAsyncResult result = myMethod.BeginInvoke(..., null);

// ...

myMethod.EndInvoke(result);
```

There are other methods you can use; using a Thread, using BackgroundWorker, etc, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET 4 you could do

```
var yourLongRunningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(DosomethingLong);
// some time later
Task.WaitAll(yourLongRunningTask);
```